# Deserialize a JSON with a nested object and a list. "JSON parse error: Cannot construct"

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to deserialize this JSON:

```
{  
"order":{  
    "address": "Adress XXX",
    "status": "Open",
    "confirmationDates": "2019-04-03"
},

"orderItems": [
        {
            "description": "Item 1",
            "unitPrice": 10.5,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "description": "Item 2",
            "unitPrice": 22.5,
            "quantity": 2
        },
        {
            "description": "Item 3",
            "unitPrice": 10000.5,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ] 
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot and have a Post request with this body.

```
@PostMapping("/orderwithitems")
public ResponseEntity<Object> addOrderWithItems(@RequestBody OrderOrderItem orderOrderItem){...}
```

The Wrapper Class is this POJO:

```
public class OrderOrderItem{
    private Order order;
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
    public OrderOrderItem(){
        orderItems = new ArrayList<>();
        order = new Order();
    }

    public OrderOrderItem(Order order, List<OrderItem> orderItems) {
        this.order = order;
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }
...
}
```

The problem is when I make the post I get this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-04T23:04:19.640+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.invillia.acme.OrderController$OrderOrderItem` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.invillia.acme.OrderController$OrderOrderItem` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]",
    "path": "/orderwithitems"
}
```

I'm trying to follow those examples: 
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-collection-array

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list

But I can't find a solution.

Comment: OrderOrderItem has no arg constructor or parmeterized? What about Order and OrderItem constructor?

Comment: @javapedia.net I add the constructors, both with and without arguments on both Order and OrderItem. Also add constructors to OrderOderItem. Still the same error.

Comment: could you drop all the constructors and retry?

Comment: @javapedia.net I droped the constructors and still it does't work.

"acme.OrderController$OrderOrderItem` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.invillia.acme.OrderController$OrderOrderItem` (although at least one Creator exists): can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 2]",

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was declaring "OrderOrderItem" as an internal Class of the controller.
Moving OrderOrderItem to a new file make things work properly.